# C++: Thread Safety in a Signal/Slot Library

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, signals-slots

I'm implementing a Signal/Slot framework, and got to the point that I want it to be thread-safe. I already had a lot of support from the Boost mailing-list, but since this is not really boost-related, I'll ask my pending question here.

When is a signal/slot implementation (or any framework that calls functions outside itself, specified in some way by the user) considered thread-safe? Should it be safe w.r.t. its own data, i.e. the data associated to its implementation details? Or should it also take into account the user's data, which might or might not be modified whatever functions are passed to the framework?

This is an example given on the mailing-list (**Edit: this is an example use-case --i.e. user code--. My code is behind the calls to the `Emitter` object**):

```
int * somePtr = nullptr;
Emitter<Event> em; // just an object that can emit the 'Event' signal    

void mainThread()
{
    em.connect<Event>(someFunction);

    // now, somehow, 2 threads are created which, at some point
    // execute the thread1() and thread2() functions below
}

void someFunction()
{
    // can somePtr change after the check but before the set?
    if (somePtr)
        *somePtr = 17;
}

void cleanupPtr()
{
    // this looks safe, but compilers and CPUs can reorder this code:
    int *tmp = somePtr;
    somePtr = null;
    delete tmp;
}

void thread1()
{
    em.emit<Event>();
}

void thread2()
{
    em.disconnect<Event>(someFunction);
    // now safe to cleanup (?)
    cleanupPtr();
}
```

In the above code, it might happen that `Event` is emitted, causing `someFunction` to be executed. If `somePtr` is non-`null`, but becomes `null` just after the `if`, but before the assignment, we're in trouble. From the point of view of `thread2`, this is not obvious because it is disconnecting `someFunction` before calling `cleanupPtr`.

I can see why this could potentially lead to trouble, but who's responsibility is this? Should my library protect the user from using it in every irresponsible but imaginable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there is no clearly good answer, but clarity will come from documenting the guarantees you wish to make about concurrent access to an Emitter object.

One level of guarantee, which to me is what is implied by a promise of thread safety, is that:

- Concurrent operations on the object are guaranteed to leave the object in a consistent state (at least, from the point of view of the accessing threads.)
- Non-commutative operations will be performed as if they were scheduled serially in some (unknown) order.

Then the question is, what does the emit method promise semantically: passing control to the connected routine, or evaluation of the function? If the former, then your work sounds like it is already done; if the latter, then the 'as-if ordered' requirement would mean that you need to enforce some level of synchronisation.

Users of the library can work with either, provided it is clear what is being promised.

Comment: Thanks, this basically confirms what I already suspected. As of now, your first bullet is guaranteed, because I'm locking the internal data that is mutated/used when the user calls `connect`, `disconnect` or `emit`. This also (I think) guarantees your second point, with emphasis on *unknown*.

Comment: It's certainly possible to make stronger guarantees, e.g.:
1. evaluation of the targets of `emit` operations on the same `Emitter` are serialized; this can be implemented with a per-`Emitter` mutex.
2. `emit` evaluations are serialized with respect to `connect` and `disconnect` operations; this can be implemented with a read-write lock.

These policies could be in-principle selectable by a policy template parameter. Nonetheless, I don't think it is at all unreasonable to expect that users of the library in a multithreaded context look after their own synchronization needs.

Answer (score 1):

The last question is easy. If you say your library is threadsafe, it should threadsafe. It makes no sense to say it is partly threadsafe or, it is only threadsafe if you do not abuse it. In that case you have to explain what exactly is not threadsafe.

Now to your first question regarded `someFunction`:
The operation is non atomic. Which means the CPU can interrupt between the `if` and the `assigment`. And that will happen, I know that :-) The other thread can erase the pointer anytime. Even between two short and fast looking statements.

Now to `cleanupPtr`:
I am not a compiler expert, but if you want to be shure that your assigment take place in the same moment you wrote it in code you should write the keyword `volatile` in front of the declaration of `somePtr`. The compiler will now know that you use that attribute in a multithreaded situation and will not buffer the value in a register of the CPU.

If you have a thread situation with a reader thread and a writer thread, the keyword `volatile` can (IMHO) be enough to sync them. As long as the attributes you use to exchange information between threads are generic. 
For other situations you can use mutex or atomics. I will give you an example for mutex. I use C++11 for that, but it works similar with previous versions of C++ using boost.

Using mutex:

```
int * somePtr = nullptr;
Emitter<Event> em; // just an object that can emit the 'Event' signal    
std::recursive_mutex g_mutex;

void mainThread()
{
    em.connect<Event>(someFunction);

    // now, somehow, 2 threads are created which, at some point
    // execute the thread1() and thread2() functions below
}

void someFunction()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(g_mutex);
    // can somePtr change after the check but before the set?
    if (somePtr)
        *somePtr = 17;
}

void cleanupPtr()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(g_mutex);
    // this looks safe, but compilers and CPUs can reorder this code:
    int *tmp = somePtr;
    somePtr = null;
    delete tmp;
}

void thread1()
{
    em.emit<Event>();
}

void thread2()
{
    em.disconnect<Event>(someFunction);
    // now safe to cleanup (?)
    cleanupPtr();
}
```

I only added a recursive mutex here without changing any other code of the sample, even if it's now cargo code.
There are two kinds of mutex in the std. A utterly useless `std::mutex` and the `std::recursive_mutex` which work like you expect a mutex should work. The `std::mutex` exclude the access of any further call even from the same thread. Which can happen if a method which needs mutex protection calls a public method which use the same mutex.  `std::recursive_mutex` is reentrant for the same thread.
Atomics (or interlocks in win32) are another way, but only to exchange values between threads or access them concurrently. Your example is missing such values, but in your case, I would look a little deeper in them (std::atomic).

**UPDATE**

If your are the user of a library which is not explicit declared as threadsafe by the developer, take it as non threadsafe and shield every call to it with a mutex lock.
To stick with the example. If you cannot change `someFunction` the you have to wrap the function like:

```
void threadsafeSomeFunction()
{
  std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(g_mutex);
  someFunction();
}
```

Comment: I know about volatile, but the problem is that I have 0 control over what the user will do. Isn't it true that I can only make sure that calls to the interface I'm providing are thread-safe, i.e. can be concurrent? The code I show is fictional user-code... there's no way I can guarantee this to work, is there?

Comment: @JorenHeit of course there is a way to get your example threadsafe. You have to use a mutex. I extend my answer with a sample-code

Comment: Sure! But again, this is not my code... So what you're actually saying is that this is indeed the responsibility of the user. Correct? Edit: just to be clear: the example-code is how a user *might* use the library. I have no control over this, and my question is whether I should bother to make this kind of use-case work thread-safely.

Comment: @JorenHeit If the developer of the library does not declare his library as threadsafe, then the user is responsible to guarantee no concurrent call. In that case, you have to shield every call to that library with a lock. And yes, there is no automatic way. Make sure that you do not have one of the seldom libraries which are threadaffin.

Comment: Exactly, and I want to know if it is correct to say that my library is thread-safe, even if this way of using it is not. Thanks btw for the stuff on `recursive_mutex`. Didn't know about this yet.

Comment: @JorenHeit Honestly I have a problem to distinguish from your part of the library and the "wrong" use of it. You are not responsible for code another developer produced. If your code is threadsafe but not his, it is his problem (and will be). A threadsafe library cannot make the overall program threadsafe (funny fact, Microsoft tried this with their COM Apartment model).

Comment: My code is behind the calls to `connect`, `disconnect` and `emit`. Sorry if this wasn't clear!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the simplest possibility: If you don't claim your library to be thread-safe, you don't have to bother about this.

(But even) if you do:
In your example the user would have to take care about thread-safety, since both functions could be dangerous, even without using your event-system (IMHO, this is a pretty good way to determine who should take care about those kind of problems). A possible way for him to do this in C++11 could be:

```
#include <mutex>

// A mutex is used to control thread-acess to a shared resource
std::mutex _somePtr_mutex;

int* somePtr = nullptr;

void someFunction()
{
    /*
        Create a 'lock_guard' to manage your mutex.

        Is the mutex '_somePtr_mutex' already locked?
            Yes: Wait until it's unlocked.
            No: Lock it and continue execution.
    */
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_somePtr_mutex);

    if(somePtr)
        *somePtr = 17;

    // End of scope: 'lock' gets destroyed and hence unlocks '_somePtr_mutex'
}

void cleanupPtr()
{
    /*
        Create a 'lock_guard' to manage your mutex.

        Is the mutex '_somePtr_mutex' already locked?
            Yes: Wait until it's unlocked.
            No: Lock it and continue execution.
    */
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_somePtr_mutex);

    int *tmp = somePtr;
    somePtr = null;
    delete tmp;

    // End of scope: 'lock' gets destroyed and hence unlocks '_somePtr_mutex'
}
```

Comment: Yep, I totally agree. On the boost mailing-list, I was led to believe that I should incorporate a degree of thread-safety such that even without modifications to the user-code (i.e. no locks added whatsoever), this code should be thread safe. From every answer so-far, it seems that this might be too much to ask...